# WEBPACK Error: Child compilation failed: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/pug-loader/index.js):

Tags: webpack, pug, pug-loader

> ERROR in   Error: Child compilation failed:
> Module build failed (from ./node_modules/pug-loader/index.js):
> TypeError: options must be an object
> at Function.validateOptions (C:\Users\user\Desktop\WEB\webpack-template\node_modules\pug-loader\index.js:67:11)
> at Object.load (C:\Users\user\Desktop\WEB\webpack-template\node_modules\pug-loader\index.js:9:8)
> ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/pug-loader/index.js):
> TypeError: options must be an object
> at Function.validateOptions (C:\Users\user\Desktop\WEB\webpack-template\node_modules\pug-loader\index.js:67:11)
> at Object.load (C:\Users\user\Desktop\WEB\webpack-template\node_modules\pug-loader\index.js:9:8)
> at processResult (C:\Users\user\Desktop\WEB\webpack-template\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:758:19)
> at C:\Users\user\Desktop\WEB\webpack-template\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:860:5
> at C:\Users\user\Desktop\WEB\webpack-template\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:400:11
> at C:\Users\user\Desktop\WEB\webpack-template\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:252:18
> at runSyncOrAsync (C:\Users\user\Desktop\WEB\webpack-template\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:156:3)
> at iterateNormalLoaders (C:\Users\user\Desktop\WEB\webpack-template\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:251  :2)
> at C:\Users\user\Desktop\WEB\webpack-template\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:224:4
> at C:\Users\user\Desktop\WEB\webpack-template\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:834:15
> at Array.eval (eval at create (C:\Users\user\Desktop\WEB\webpack-template\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:  33:10), :12:1)
> at runCallbacks (C:\Users\user\Desktop\WEB\webpack-template\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\CachedInputFileSystem.js  :27:15)

- index.js:67 Function.validateOptions
  [webpack-template]/[pug-loader]/index.js:67:11
- index.js:9 Object.load
  [webpack-template]/[pug-loader]/index.js:9:8
- ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/pug-loader/index.js):
- TypeError: options must be an object
- index.js:67 Function.validateOptions
  [webpack-template]/[pug-loader]/index.js:67:11
- index.js:9 Object.load
  [webpack-template]/[pug-loader]/index.js:9:8
- NormalModule.js:758 processResult
  [webpack-template]/[webpack]/lib/NormalModule.js:758:19
- NormalModule.js:860
  [webpack-template]/[webpack]/lib/NormalModule.js:860:5
- LoaderRunner.js:400
  [webpack-template]/[loader-runner]/lib/LoaderRunner.js:400:11
- LoaderRunner.js:252
  [webpack-template]/[loader-runner]/lib/LoaderRunner.js:252:18
- LoaderRunner.js:156 runSyncOrAsync
  [webpack-template]/[loader-runner]/lib/LoaderRunner.js:156:3
- LoaderRunner.js:251 iterateNormalLoaders
  [webpack-template]/[loader-runner]/lib/LoaderRunner.js:251:2
- LoaderRunner.js:224
  [webpack-template]/[loader-runner]/lib/LoaderRunner.js:224:4
- NormalModule.js:834
  [webpack-template]/[webpack]/lib/NormalModule.js:834:15
- CachedInputFileSystem.js:27 runCallbacks
  [webpack-template]/[enhanced-resolve]/lib/CachedInputFileSystem.js:27:15
- child-compiler.js:169
  [webpack-template]/[html-webpack-plugin]/lib/child-compiler.js:169:18
- Compiler.js:551 finalCallback
  [webpack-template]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:551:5
- Compiler.js:577
  [webpack-template]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:577:11
- Compiler.js:1196
  [webpack-template]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:1196:17
- Hook.js:18 Hook.CALL_ASYNC_DELEGATE [as _callAsync]
  [webpack-template]/[tapable]/lib/Hook.js:18:14
- Compiler.js:1192
  [webpack-template]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:1192:33
- Compilation.js:2787 finalCallback
  [webpack-template]/[webpack]/lib/Compilation.js:2787:11
- Compilation.js:3092
  [webpack-template]/[webpack]/lib/Compilation.js:3092:11

Hi all, i learn webpack and i need connect pug-loader. But in installation time in terminal writte message about pug-load(i used pug-loader), i didn't pay attention to it and continued on. As a result, the assembly fails to compile

```
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin')

let mode = 'development'
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    mode = 'production'
}

console.log(mode + ' mode')

module.exports = {
    mode: mode,
    output: {
        assetModuleFilename: "assets/[hash][ext][query]",
        clean: true,
    },
    plugins: [
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: '[name].[contenthash].css'
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: "./src/index.pug"
    })],
    module: {
        rules: [ {
            test: /\.html$/i,
            loader: "html-loader",
        },
            {
                test: /\.(sa|sc|c)ss$/,
                use: [
                    (mode === 'development') ? "style-loader" : MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    "css-loader",
                    {loader: "postcss-loader"},
                    "sass-loader",
                ],
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|jpeg|gif|)$/i,
                type: 'asset/resource',
            },
            {
                test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|otf|)$/i,
                type: 'asset/resource',
            },
            {
                test: /\.pug$/,
                loader: 'pug-loader',
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
            },
        ]
    },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The pug-loader is not maintained over 5 years.
Instead of the combo (html-webpack-plugin, mini-css-extract-plugin, pug-loader, html-loader) you can simplify Webpack config using the modern pug-plugin.

There is the working example for your use case.

*./src/index.pug*

```
html
  head
    //- load source styles here
    link(href=require('./style.scss') rel='stylesheet')
    //- load source scripts here and/or in body
    script(src=require('./main.js') defer='defer')
  body
    h1 Hello World!
```

The generated HTML:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="css/style.f57966f4.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="js/main.b855d8f4.js" defer="defer"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello Pug!</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

*Webpack config*

```js
const path = require('path');
const PugPlugin = require('pug-plugin');

const mode = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'production' : 'development';

module.exports = {
  mode,

  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist/'),
    assetModuleFilename: "assets/[hash][ext][query]",
    clean: true,
  },

  entry: {
    // define Pug files here
    index: './src/index.pug', // => dist/index.html
  },

  plugins: [
    new PugPlugin({
      js: {
        filename: 'js/[name].[contenthash:8].js', // output filename of JS
      },
      css: {
        filename: 'css/[name].[contenthash:8].css', // output filename of CSS
      },
    }),
  ],

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.pug$/,
        loader: PugPlugin.loader,
      },
      {
        test: /\.(sa|sc|c)ss$/,
        use: ['css-loader', 'postcss-loader', 'sass-loader'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|jpeg|gif|)$/i,
        type: 'asset/resource',
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|otf|)$/i,
        type: 'asset/resource',
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

The Pug plugin automatically extract CSS and JS from source files specified directly in the Pug template.

Comment: great thank ))) i find very good article about Webpack besides webpack.js.org )) Unfortunately i was watching an old video...and i'm not convinced of its relevance